# Retrieving a value in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
var $form = $(' <form id="login"> </form> ');
$form.append('<label id="datakeylbl" for="datakey"> Enter Datakey');
$form.append('<input type="text" name="datakey" id="datakey"/>');
$form.append('<input type="submit" value="Login In" />');
$("#main").append($form);

var data = $("#datakey").val();
```

Unsure of why data does not get the value of the text in the datakey
textfield.

Comment: do you want to get the value on load ? it would be empty anyhow

Comment: You are creating the control without a value and then almost immediately after asking for it. Since it doesn't exist, nothing to return.

Comment: `data` is set up to get the value of the input immediately, which is a blank textbox.

Answer (score 1):

data value would be empty on load. you should try something like this to get the value.

**JsFiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/G5ezv/**

```
var $form = $(' <form id="login"> </form> ');
$form.append('<label id="datakeylbl" for="datakey"> Enter Datakey');
$form.append('<input type="text" name="datakey" id="datakey"/>');
$form.append('<input type="submit" value="Login In" />');
$("#main").append($form);

$("#login").on("submit",function(){
    var data = $("#datakey").val();    
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var data = "";

$( "#datakey" ).keyup(function() {
  data = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code and it works fine:

```
var $form = $('<form id="login"/>').append(
    '<label id="datakeylbl" for="datakey">Enter Datakey</label>',
    '<input type="type" name="datakey" id="datakey"/>',
    '<input type="submit" value="Login"/>'
).appendTo('#main').on('submit', function (event) {
    //-- prevent the form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();
    //-- grab the data from the text field
    var data = $("#datakey").val();
    //-- alert the data for troubleshooting
    alert(data);
});
```

I made the following changes:

1. I merged the code into a single `append()` call, rather than multiple calls.
2. I added your `data` code into a `submit` event.

Comment: Careful when using `return false`: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: Good point, I just sort of tacked it on at the end for my own testing - I assumed that the alert and return were just throwaway code, but I'll update my sample.

Comment: Yeah, it's not "wrong" per se, but sometimes I tremble when I think about how many people might be "learning" how to write JS from StackOverflow posts. Thanks for updating it; perhaps it will help some newcomer to avoid a potential pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is exactly how you posted, you are appending the form and immediately getting the field val. That way the field will be empty.

Can you try this code below? I made small changes and it is showing the "datakey" value only when the "Login In" is hit:

```
var $form = $(' <form id="login"> </form> ');
$form.append('<label id="datakeylbl" for="datakey"> Enter Datakey');
$form.append('<input type="text" name="datakey" id="datakey"/>');
$form.append('<input type="submit" id="login-button" value="Login In" />');
$("#main-form").append($form);

$('#login-button').click( function()
{
    var data = $("#datakey").val();
    alert( data );
    return false;
});
```

Maybe if you provide more details I can help you more.